# trouble adding athorization in headers using jwt authoriation react js?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-redux, jwt

im trying to make a authorization with bearer token from my front to my api, in my api all its working i testing all with insmonia, the problem is in the front when i try to add an Authorization in the headers in this way, im using react-redux for the store so and redux-persist for persist for the data persisting and when i try add this

```
     export function setToken({ payload }) {
      if (!payload) return;
    
      const { token } = payload.auth;
    
      if (token) {
        api.defaults.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
    }
   export default all([
    takeLatest('@auth/persist/REHYDRATE', setToken),
    takeLatest('@auth/SIGN_IN_REQUEST', signIn),
    takeLatest('@auth/SIGN_UP_REQUEST', signUp),
  ]);
```

but when i reload my admin page where i make my httprequests(post/get etc) in the browser its no reciving the authorization in the headers and say
**createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401**

```
    Request URL: http://localhost:3333/notifications
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:3333
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

RESPONSE HEADERS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2021 00:52:14 GMT
ETag: W/"17-IQ4NhR9c983ggGeU6wL1lrE99jM"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
X-Powered-By: Express


REQUEST HEADERS
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3333
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-GPC: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.101 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

whats im doing wrong? how can i add the authorization with bearer and the token?

HERE IS MY PROJECT REPOSITORY IF HELPS TO UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM
https://github.com/dariocoroneldev/Error

Comment: i try it importing axios and making this way.       
      axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;                               
     but even that way stiil not working

Comment: I haven't used `redux-persist` specifically so I can't say if there is an issue related to that, but I'm assuming it will reload the state, but it will do so without calling any of your actions, and so `setToken` is never called, and as such auth is never set.

I personally have a similar setup except I grab my saved token at the top level of my app and make sure to set it on load. I also keep track on when auth is set or not, and usually wait for it to be applied before I many any API calls by using ''useEffects'.

Comment: As a side note from personal experience, I also use redux-thunk for my API calls and I can easily access the state and insert the header to all `fetch` calls without having to pass it into the action. I also have a state variable for each API call so I can easily keep track of what is loading or finished or has some error etc.

Comment: thanks so much for the advice, i gonna research about redux-thunk, i never hear about it, may can help me thanks

Comment: redux-thunk won't be a solution to this question on it's own, but can make life easier, especially for auth and API calls in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

When i add Authorization in to headers outside from my function setToken()
anywhere from the app, then it work, but if i do this, i do it like manually just for test, cuze i dont know how to get my token outside the setToken()

```
const tokentest =
  'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwiaWF0IjoxNjEwMzE3NDcwLCJleHAiOjE2OTY2MzEwNzB9.TikP-RQknI5YMVZmirTH69agd2P0zsW5jIHFcK27kO8';

api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokentest}`;
```

now the problem is not more send the authorization,  now i dont know how to get my token outside the setToken function that using a actions thats i generated by the react-perssit library, so here my code

```
 import { takeLatest, call, put, all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
    import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
    import history from '~/services/history';
    import api from '~/services/api';
    import { signInSuccess, signFailure } from './actions';
    
    // const test = api.defaults.headers.Authorization;
    // console.log(test);

      //here it work, but how can i get my token from here?
      //why just working here and not inside my fucntion?

      const tokentest =
  'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MiwiaWF0IjoxNjEwMzE3NDcwLCJleHAiOjE2OTY2MzEwNzB9.TikP-RQknI5YMVZmirTH69agd2P0zsW5jIHFcK27kO8';

api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${tokentest}`;
    
    export function* signIn({ payload }) {
      try {
        const { email, password } = payload;
    
        const response = yield call(api.post, 'session', {
          email,
          password,
        });
        const { token, user } = response.data;
    
        if (!user.provider) {
          toast.error('usario no es porveedor');
        }

         //but here doe'snt work nothing when i do this
    
         api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    
        yield put(signInSuccess(token, user));
    
        history.push('/admin');
      } catch (err) {
        toast.error('error de autenticacion, verifique sus datos');
        yield put(signFailure());
      }
    }
    
    export function* signUp({ payload }) {
      try {
        const { name, email, password, whatsapp, repeatPassword } = payload;
        yield call(api.post, 'users', {
          name,
          email,
          password,
          whatsapp,
          repeatPassword,
          provider: true,
        });
    
        history.push('/sesion');
      } catch (err) {
        toast.error('error al registarse');
        yield put(signFailure());
      }
    }
       //here not working too
    export function setToken({ payload }) {
      if (!payload) return;
      const { token } = payload.auth;
      console.log(token);
      if (token) {
        api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
    }
    
    export default all([
      takeLatest('@auth/persist/REHYDRATE', setToken),
      takeLatest('@auth/SIGN_IN_REQUEST', signIn),
      takeLatest('@auth/SIGN_UP_REQUEST', signUp),
    ]);
```

**why just working here and not inside my fucntion?**